# How does PKCS#7 padding work with AES-256, CBC mode?

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm a bit confused with AES-256, CBC, and how it works with padding (PKCS#7).

Whenever I encrypt data of multiples of 16 bytes (the block size), extra 16 bytes are always padded at the end.

For instance, a 1600 byte file turns into a 1616 byte encrypted file.

If I look into the file with a hex editor, the last 16 bytes are not all zeros at all. I don't see any particular pattern either.

An explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The padding is done *before encryption*. It ensures that what will be given to the encryption algorithm can be split into an integral number of blocks (16 bytes per block with AES). AES encrypts the whole, data *and* padding, and encrypted data "looks random".

*After decryption*, the original contents of the padding are revealed, and will exhibit the proper structure (namely that the extra bytes all have value *n* if *n* extra bytes were added -- *n = 16* in your example).

Comment: I still don't get how padding can be done *before* encryption, because often we are encrypting the whole data in small pieces at a time, until we hit the end. At the end there is usually a "finalize" function that is supposed to take care of the padding. So how did it happen before encryption? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Application sends data. When a full block is received, the block is encrypted. At any one time, between 0 and 15 bytes are still buffered. The "finalize" function is called: between 1 and 16 bytes are appended to the buffered data (to reach the length of 16), and that final block is encrypted like all the others. If 0 bytes were buffered at that point, 16 padding bytes are appended (all of numerical value 16), and that extra block is encrypted (leading to the seemingly random bytes).